# ruby soap datatime adds Z at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some strange behavior with ruby.

In a rake file I pass in a date to soap method. In the response it appends a Z at the end of the date.

in a lib file, same thing, same requirements, it doesn't.

I need the case where it doesn't. It executes the same.

What could it be?

```
      <n1:startDate>2009-08-18T00:00:00-05:00Z</n1:startDate>
      <n1:endDate>2009-08-26T00:00:00-05:00Z</n1:endDate>
```

Answer (score 2):

The letter at the end is an indicator of the timezone (in this case UTC). The timestamp is in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO%5F8601) format (pretty much the standard now-a-days for all things internet), so I'm not sure why you'd want otherwise.

Without seeing the code that's generating it I'm not sure what more I can offer. Why do you want it without the 'Z'?

Answer (score 0):

You've got an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date there, the Z indicates 'Zulu' time or UTC, but not sure why you're getting differing formats though.

Answer (score 0):

I am accessing an API which doesn t support this ISO standard. The date should not have a Z at the end. but when the soap response is build, it adds it. And I don t send it with that Z .. as I pass it to the web method.

Here is the code

```
 factory = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(WSDL_STATS)
  driver = factory.create_rpc_driver
  driver.wiredump_dev = STDOUT

  response = driver.getAllLeads({"pubID" => AFF_ID_TEST, "startDate" => start_date, "endDate" => end_date})
```

The end date that are passed, tried various .. isn t with that Z , from zone, at the end.

If I overwritte the zone method, maybe it will work, but I don t want to do that.

```
<n1:startDate>2009-08-18T00:00:00-05:00Z</n1:startDate>
  <n1:endDate>2009-08-26T00:00:00-05:00Z</n1:endDate>
```

I pass the date without the Z, but when the soap is constructed the Z is added somehow.

This is what I want

```
<n1:startDate>2009-08-18T00:00:00-05:00</n1:startDate>
  <n1:endDate>2009-08-26T00:00:00-05:00</n1:endDate>
```

Thank you ;)